# I have a PNG image, and wondering how to efficiently convert it to PBM in python

Tags: python, image, png, pbm

Is there any simple way for converting PNG to PBM?

ocrad requires PBM image, not PNG.

Comment: @Jean--François Corbett : [Regarding the edit] Wow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/). According to [the docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/image-file-formats.html#ppm), it supports PBM, PGM, and PPM formats out of the box. The following code should get you started:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("myfile.png")
im.save("myfile.pbm")
```

Comment: On my 1001pxd used as a router it works perfectly, although on OS X 10.9.5 `sudo easy_install PIL` returns: https://gist.github.com/ArchieT/ceceb64a43b5d268dde2

Comment: @ArchieT install using `pip`. Also, the package name is `pillow`, not `PIL`. Pillow is a fork of PIL, massively and continuously updated. `PIL` is ancient.

Comment: `gietwenti:~ mf$ sudo pip install PIL --allow-external PIL
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL
  Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified PIL to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PIL
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/mf/.pip/pip.logz`

Installing pillow using pip theoretically worked, but I cannot import it. And installing pillow using easy_install: [my gist link above]

Comment: I've read the documentation from your link; `sudo easy_install Pillow` — worked. And they wrote to not to use pip as it doesn't support Python Eggs. Anyway, thanks for a great and fast answer!